# Query to use in backend to retrieve all contacts with recent sent date less than or equal to some date

Tags: php, mysql

In my task I want a query to retrieve all contacts with recent sent date, on the condition that it is less than or equal to some fixed date.

Actually I have one table name `XXX` which contains `email`, `name`, and `sentdate`.

Each year from 2006 to 2012, the mail is sent to each email contact. For some contacts still the mail is sent for every year from 2006 to 2012. For some contacts the mail has not been sent after 2007. So some contacts have received mail more recently than others.

I need a query to retrieve all the contacts with last sent date less than or equal to some date (for example, "01-01-2010").

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `xxx` WHERE `last_sent_date`<='some_date'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But i need backend query for retrieving all contacts which has last send email date of each contacts which is <='01-01-2010'.  For Eg: If Subha has received two mails with two different date as '12-09-2009' in one mail and '24-08-2007' in another mail.For her 12-09-2009 is the recent received email send date. Like this i need the email contacts of a person who had received last send email date.Like this i need to retrieve all contacts from one table from using this condition which is <=01-01-2010. Can you help me.....

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
  SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE sent_date<='01-01-2010'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.But i need backend query for retrieving all contacts which has last sent email date which is <='01-01-2010'.